# Is it a good practice in general to use GET requests for a route that implies a high load on the server?

Tags: web-applications, routes, http-verbs

Suppose you have a web application that exposes a route, which when called executes a pretty intensive search server side before returning the data to the client. Suppose there are no side effects of the search, and the route is secured so no one can hack around it and abuse it.

I have encountered various behaviors of browsers (Chrome mainly, an old bug which kept appearing from time to time) and sometimes front end web frameworks in which GET requests are either sent multiple times or are retried upon a certain timeout.

Given this does it make sense to have the route as a GET route, main argument being that the only thing it does is serve data, or would it be better with another verb, let's say POST?